# Using Yeoman/Grunt.js with FlatFile CMS

Tags: content-management-system, gruntjs, yeoman, flat-file, kirby

I'm about to start devlopment of a new website and want to use yeoman/grunt to speed up development/testing. However the site needs to be build with limited CMS functionallty with a flatfile cms such as http://getkirby.com/. Now I'm a little confused as to how to use these tools together?

Anyone had previous experience with this or have any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a Kirby site with a grunt taskrunner for developement-stuff. I use coffeescript, sass, minification, linting, autoprefixer etc. You could have a look at [my current grundfile.coffee](https://github.com/DerZyklop/der-zyklop.de/blob/master/gruntfile.coffee) or [an earlier version of my gruntfile.coffee](https://gist.github.com/DerZyklop/cb3a4310dd21415b68cf). I guess they are a good start point - you could pick some tasks you need, and add your own stuff.

But i'm not sure if it answers your question, because all this is nothing Kirby-specific, except the file-paths. So if this is no help, you could specify your question/issue.

Comment: @user2541153 if this was helpful to you, id appreciate a upvote or a correct-answer-checkmark